# RecyclerView and SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, studio

Tengo un problema con RecyclerView y SwipeRefreshLayout, el problema es que al refrescar el RecyclerView me trae todos los datos repetidos que ya al principio se cargo, quiero que solo el ultimo dato ingresado en la base de datos me muestre. Gracias.

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    View vista =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);

    rv1 = vista.findViewById(R.id.rv1);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    swipeRefreshLayout = vista.findViewById(R.id.swipe1);

   GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
   rv1.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

   rv1.setHasFixedSize(true);

    peliculas = new ArrayList<>();

    mostrarDatos();

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mostrarDatos();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    return vista;

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega siempre el código como texto, ya que como imagen no es visible para todos los miembros de la comunidad. Revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Esto soluciona tu problema?

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        peliculas.clear(); //limpia la lista antes de volver a cargarla
        mostrarDatos();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
});
```